# How to schedule a weekly backup of a database only if it has been changed since last backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, stored-procedures

I´m new to SQL Server administration.

I´d like to create automatically backup database every Sunday night, but **only if there was any change in previous week** (if not, backup is unnecessary).

Is there some way how to do that only with SQL Server, like some automatic procedure or something like that?

Comment: There are many reasons why this isn't practical.  Use a differential backup and then don't worry about it...

Comment: @VilemRousi, I just answered your question on how to backup only the changes. However if we need to explain how to automate something for example "making backups" in general please say so. I've no idea on how new you are to MS SQL.

Comment: @Edward Dortland - Thank you, for quick answer. About my database skills - I´m not new in SQL, but this is my first time, I want to administrate MSSQL. This question is last step of my school project for. I have a program C# which read and write data to SQL DB. 
Originally I thought about backup DB from program when user will updating the DB, but at last I don´t want to burden DB in every update, so I decide to use some automatic procedure or something like that for automatic backup in side of server.

Comment: How big is the database?

Comment: It´s very small. Only 8 tables, with 50 rows in each table.

Comment: okay than in that case. just create simple maintenance plan that will create a daily full backup. Your database is so small, it doesn;t really matter that you backup only the changes or the full. In the maintenance plan you can also say that backups older than x days should be deleted. You need further explaining on how to set that up?

Comment: I think I can handle it with MSDN :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to MS SQL :-)

To start with your question:

Yes there is. First you make a full database backup:

```
BACKUP DATABASE yourdatabasename
TO DISK = "pathtobackupdir\backupfilename.bak"
```

Now from that moment on a so called differential bitmap is keeping track of all pages changed.

From that moment every time you create a DIFFERENTIAL backup, only the pages that changed since your last FULL backup will be backupped.

```
 BACKUP DATABASE yourdatabasename
    TO DISK = "pathtobackupdir\backupfilename.bak" WITH DIFFERENTIAL
```

So every sunday, asuming you had changes every week, the diff backup will be bigger then the previous one. Untill one sunday, it's just as big as a full backup would be. That would imply that all data pages had changed. At that moment you want to do a new full backup. Since that will reset the differential bitmap and your next diff backup will be small again. (depending on the amount of changes)

You could automate the process of making diff backups untill a certain percentage of the data has changed. Have a look at this blog post: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/New-script-How-much-of-the-database-has-changed-since-the-last-full-backup.aspx
It explains a way on how to programatically look up the percentage of database changes. That way you could say.. make diff backups if percentage changed < 75% otherwise make a full backup.

Now could you tell me why you want this? Because this isn't a setup I would advise a starter (with exceptions). So please elaborate a bit and we can see if this is the best solution for your setup. How big is your database?  how much changes do you have? is batch based changes? Which version and Edition of SQL do you have do you have?

Comment: + 1 for the answer :) Is it ok to do this kind of backup? Because in my work I do backup in the on the server generously..Our database is quite big because I am working in a College Institution.

Comment: The only problem that I see with the diff backups is that if some one takes an **ad-hoc** full backup **without COPY_ONLY**, then the diff would be useless affecting the recovery process.